# Attach debugger not working for Azure Websites in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

Attach debugger not working for Azure Websites in visual studio 2015

I am getting Below error

Please help

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Unable to configure remote debugger.

Could not load properties

Could not load app settings

### Could not load connection strings

### OK

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Yes Microsoft fixed this issue.. check this link (Check last 10 comments from the post) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/22fa1009-a276-4b3b-8085-3cc639a90690/staging-instance-not-showing-up-in-visual-studio?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

What I did was I updated my PC with latest Updates
NOTE: Make sure you also select this option "Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update windows"

Answer (score 33):

I cringed for this problem for about 3 hours. The solution was to manually attach the debugger through Visual Studio's "Attach to Process".

Here are the steps.

1) Let's enter to Azure's portal @ https://portal.azure.com, and head to your App Services directory (as shown in the image).

2) Click on the App you would like to debug.

[image]

3) Click Settings or All Settings (both will launch the "All Settings" blade)

[image]

4) Go to Application Settings and **scroll down**. In there you will see "Remote Debugging". It is very important to check that this is turned on, as the image show. Select your appropriate Visual Studio version. Note, that if you're visiting from the classic portal you **will not** be able to select Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

5) Press Save.

If you have never set up an FTP account for your App Service, continue reading, otherwise jump to step 8.

6) In the already opened "All Settings" blade, scroll down and look for "Deployment credentials". In here you will **create** an FTP username and password. Put whatever you want. Of course, I recommend you to use a different username than your account and a [strong password](http://passwordsgenerator.net/) for it.

[image]

7) Click Save.

8) In case you've forgotten about your FTP username, in the main page of your web app (where you clicked "All Settings"), you will have your deployment username. In this example, you will use the one that goes after the slash. If it is  mywebsite\userftp you will use *userftp*.

[image]

9) Let's head to Visual Studio. Open the project you want to debug, and select the "DEBUG" tab.

[image]

10) Click on "Attach Process". Of course, you can just hit Alt + P and that will also open the window for you!

11) Now you will focus in the Qualifier. Put in there your azurewebsites.net domain. You could try with your .com domain, but in my case it didn't work. I am using [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) to enable https on my shared Azure website and it seems that it is filtering the connection with the debugger.

12) Press Enter on your Keyboard or hit "Refresh" button.

[image]

13) The following prompt will appear:

[image]

14) As the picture says: The username will be: theSameWebsiteYouPutInTheQualifier.azurewebsites.net**.**exampleftp

Please note the following:

a) You must put the same website URL you put in the qualifier.

b) You must put the dot and the backward slash after the .net or .com

c) You must put your FTP username. Remember after reading point 8, that if you lose this one, you must check on Azure website and use the name after the backward slash.

Press OK. If you receive some errors, check that Remote Debugging is turned on. It has happened to me that it has turned off without noticing.

15) Select w3wp.exe and press "Attach"
[image]

16) This shall put you with the goody orange "Ready" bar :D

[image]

Comment: Your answer save my life. Thanks. Btw, my case. in step 13) the username and password I did put exactly the same from publishing profile. (the username part is NAME\$NAME ) http://i.stack.imgur.com/A06Nz.png
) Note: publishing profile can be downloaded from the down-arrow in the App Service blade 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/DWYvT.png

Comment: You are welcome! Really glad to help! :D Interesting about your username. Thanks for letting everyone know!

Comment: Thanks for this... I don't get the prompt in step 13... It never asks for my username and pw for ftp... any ideas ? Here is my error - it seems to want the ftp user and pw: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named 'mytestsitethatwillnotdebugfff.azurewebsites.net'.  The Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing. String site, String user, String password)

Comment: Thanks for all this great detail! I needed an outbound port (3702) opened to allow the debugger to attach... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt592018.aspx.

Comment: The ftp user did not work for me. I found somewhere that you can use the credentials from the publish settings that you can download from Azure for your website. I used those credentials and it worked.

Comment: It appears that the connection credentials have changed to using the publish profile credentials as @elector said

Comment: @ScottLance and elector Thanks for pointing it out. I believe (I could be wrong), the publishing profile has been in use for a while. The method above I've used it whenever the publishing profile is giving me problems. If the publishing profile is working, there is no reason to use this method ;)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your project settings are correct, this will often resolve the issue:

- Go to the Azure portal and Stop / Restart your web app

If that doesn't work:

- Close Visual Studio.
- Go to the Azure portal and Stop / Restart your web app
- Restart visual studio

Comment: Reinstall Visual Studio -> Restart your PC -> Apply Latest Windows Updates -> cmd sfc /scannow -> Boot into safe mode -> Use a recovery Disk -> Reinstall your windows -> Put a bullet into your head.

Answer (score 1):

Much more surefire route at http://blog.falafel.com/remote-debugging-azure-websites-day-31-visual-studio-2015/ .

Open up server explorer. 
Navigate in through the azure node to your web app.
right-mouse and attach debugger.

Configures all the goodies

Comment: I that worked, I wouldn't be googling for a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a false positive error dialog. If you just press Ok, the debugger attaches to the Azure web app despite showing this dialog.
[image]