# Azure remote debugger from Visual Studio not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, remote-debugging

I was able to remotely debug this website before. Now when I try to do it, through VS 2013 Server Explorer (Attach debugger), it is giving me

> The following error occurred while launching remote debugging:  Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named 'mywebsite.azurewebsites.net'.  The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.

This website has a certificate and it's running over https. The remote debugging is enabled in the Settings with the correct VS version.

I have two other websites on this host and I can attach a debugger to them.

It is driving me crazy, I have googled and tried all the suggested solutions but it just seems that the remote debugger is not responding form Azure. 
Even when attaching manually (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35738995/1057052), I still get the same error in return.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I am having same issue with VS 2017

Comment: No, sorry. I have moved away from Azure. Found it slow and overpriced.