# Azure remote debugging not working with .NET core web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, remote-debugging

I've been trying to get an ASP.NET Core web api to work with Azure remote debugging.  So far no luck.  I've tried Server Explorer, right-click on my App Service and say Attach to Debugger.  I can tell it configured everything because it turned on my debugging and set right VS version etc.  It just won't take my breakpoint.

I also tried manually attaching by putting my website.azurewebsites.net into the Qualifier but it fails with error: "remote server name is not valid".  I know the app works because I can hit one of the REST endpoints, but I can't debug the app at all.

I tried the ideas in this helpful stackoverflow article as well: [Attach debugger not working for Azure Websites in visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885549/attach-debugger-not-working-for-azure-websites-in-visual-studio-2015)  But it didn't work.

Finally, I tried a brand new ASP.NET 4.5 project (not core) and it seems the debugging is working for the most part.  Are .NET Core apps able to be debugged in App Service?

Any ideas?

James

Comment: Did you have anyluck with this?

Comment: @Master Unfortunately no.  There were alot of things wrong with my project at the time, but in the end for me even a plain ASP.NET Core project did not seem to debug.  I contacted Microsoft and they refused to help me without creating at least two different support incidents which was ridiculous.  So I went to outputting stuff to logging and watching Azure logs to debug my issues.  Not ideal, but I didn't have any more time to deal with MS support.  In the end they cost me almost a week of my time and did not help me.

Comment: @Master - all that being said if I can help you in any way let me know.  I've learned alot since and may have some ideas for you.