# How to Debug a Docker Container in VS2019

Tags: docker, containers, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to use VS2019 to debug my program in a container.  When I click F5 to start debugging Visual Studio displays the error "The Visual Studio 2019 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer"

[image]

When I run my project with out debugging it starts up correctly.
Do I need to update the Dockerfile to include the remote debugger? if so how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio debug error about MSVSMON.EXE not appear to be running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348309/visual-studio-debug-error-about-msvsmon-exe-not-appear-to-be-running)

Comment: no that doesn't solve my problem.  Proxifier is not running on my server and I've never heard of it before.